# Logarithmic Sum

Tags: summation, gamma-function, polygamma

Is there a closed form for the following sum? $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+n}\frac{\ln(m+n)}{(m+n)}$$
According to https://www.mathmash.org/contestprob.php?prob=227 it has a closed form. Using Mathematica we get $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+n}\frac{\ln(m+n)}{(m+n)}=\frac{1}{2} (-1)^n \left(\ln2 \left(-\text{PolyGamma}\left[0,1+\frac{n}{2}\right]+\text{PolyGamma}\left[0,\frac{1+n}{2}\right]\right)-\text{StieltjesGamma}\left[1,\frac{1+n}{2}\right]+\text{StieltjesGamma}\left[1,\frac{2+n}{2}\right]\right)$$

Comment: Aren't you trying to cheat? The problem has a simple answer.

Comment: Why will you say that? I am not trying to cheat. Contest is already over.

Comment: My bad. I thought the contest was still going on.

Comment: Can you tell how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{m=1}(-1)^{n+m}\frac{\log(n+m)}{n+m} =&\ \lim_{s\rightarrow 0^+} \sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{m=1}(-1)^{n+m}\frac{\log(n+m)}{(n+m)^{1+s}}\\
 =&\ \lim_{s\rightarrow 0^+}\sum^\infty_{j=1}(-1)^j\frac{\log(j)}{j^s} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align}

**Edit:** I used something called the [Dirichlet regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) to sum up the series. For example,

\begin{align}
``\sum^\infty_{n=1} 1"  = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0^+} ``\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^s}" = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0^+} \zeta(s) = -\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
There is quite a bit of handwaviness to the above "solution/hint". The point is for the reader to rigorously justify each step.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot :)